# TableForm behavior change

Tags: output-formatting, version-9

In an older version NoteBook, I was able to specify some options for `TableForm`, which enabled
the printing of an expression in a simple fashion:

```
MyExpression//TableForm
```

I used this:

```
optsinit1 := SetOptions[TableForm,
  TableHeadings -> {rowHeadings, columnHeadings},
  TableAlignments -> Left,
  TableSpacing -> 1]
```

where rowHeadings and columnHeadings were defined.

Before using `TableForm` I would evaluate optsinit1:

```
optsinit1;

MyExpression//TableForm
```

would print the array (MyExpression) with the headings defined by rowHeadings and columnHeadings.

In V9Ii have to issue

```
TableForm[MyExpression,optsinit1]
```

to get the previous behavior.

I prefer the old behavior. Any hints on how this is done?

Note that when I issue `Options[TableForm]` the return is

```
{TableAlignments -> Left, TableDepth -> \[Infinity], 
 TableDirections -> Column, 
 TableHeadings -> {rowHeadings, colHeadings}, TableSpacing -> 1}
```

Comment: What version were you using that gave you the "correct" behavior? (Run `SystemInformation["Small"]`, please.)

Comment: The version that 'worked' was 5.2.